# weblogic to Jboss Migratiion JaxB issue : unknown enum constant AccessType.FIELD

Tags: jboss, jaxb, migration

We are trying to migrate one of our java application from WebLogic to JBOSS
and once we upgrade the jaxb jar from 2.0 to 2.2 we are getting the below warning.

Even deployment also we are getting same error.
We have also upgraded spring jars to 4.3.10 .
Spring annotation is looking for Access Type but JaxB 2.2 is returning 
XmlAccessType.

> warning: unknown enum constant AccessType.FIELD

Comment: Compiling 21 source files to 
    [javac] warning: unknown enum constant AccessType.FIELD
    [javac]   reason: class file for javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType not found
    [javac] warning: unknown enum constant AccessType.FIELD
    [javac] warning: unknown enum constant AccessType.FIELD
    [javac] warning: unknown enum constant AccessType.FIELD
....

Comment: They're just warnings - does the application actually work? Also by chance are you upgrading from Java 7 to 8?

Comment: yeh this are warning but main issue is with deployment in JBOSS we see similar issue and we have upgrade this from JDK 1.7 to 1.8

Comment: Someone mentioned you can get that warning when upgrading java versions - might just try it out and see if it works.  If it works, answer your own question so others facing the same issue don't wonder about it!  FYI, I get warnings in JBoss on injected resource entries, but the resources are available to the app, went to JBoss Developer Forums and they said not to worry about it O_o ;-)

Comment: We have tried to build in 1.7 and 1.8 , getting same warning , but ignoring this is resulting deployment issue .

Comment: While not the best solution, have you tried bundling JAX-B 2.0 with your deployment and adding it as a dependency in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml.  It might be a workaround.

Comment: yeh , we tried this but it only works while we add jar in global module.

Comment: What about specifically excluding it in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml and then you might not have to deal with the global module?  I had to do that with the JMS subsystem recently?